# How to make a setOnItemClickListener work for a ListView with a CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, onitemclicklistener, android-viewholder

I have a little project to manage the landed tricks for football freestylers.

The app is like that TVShowTime app that manages our shows.

The landed button is working, inside the item list, see my list view below.

[image: listview]

Everything works fine but when I click in any item from the list nothing happens.

Thank you.

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {

    private String[] tricks;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Activity context;
    private boolean isClicked;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, String[] tricks, ImageView unmastered) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_listview_tricks, tricks);

        this.context = context;
        this.tricks = tricks;
        this.imageView = unmastered;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View r= convertView;

        viewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(r==null){

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            r = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_tricks, null, true);
            viewHolder = new viewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {

            viewHolder = (CustomAdapter.viewHolder) r.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.textView1.setText(tricks[position]);

        viewHolder.unmastered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unmastered);

        final CustomAdapter.viewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;

        viewHolder.unmastered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if(isClicked){
                    finalViewHolder.unmastered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mastered);
                }else{
                    finalViewHolder.unmastered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unmastered);
                }
                isClicked = !isClicked;

            }
        });

viewHolder.textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return r;
    }


    class viewHolder{

        TextView textView1;
        ImageView unmastered;
        viewHolder (View v){

            textView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.name_xml);
            unmastered = v.findViewById(R.id.unmastered_xml);

        }

    }

}
```

**TricksActivity**

```
public class TricksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] lower = {

            "ATW - Around the World",
            "HTW - Hop the World",
            "Crossover",
            "Crossover 360",
            "Simple Crossover",
            "Reverse Crossover",
            "KATW - Knee Around the World",
            "KHTW - Knee Hop the World",
            "Toe Bounce",
            "Reverse Toe Bounce",
            "Air Jester",
            "ATL - Around the Leg",
            "Hell Juggles"

    };

    private ImageView imageView;


    private int codigo;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tricks);


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.unmastered_xml);
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mastered);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        codigo = intent.getIntExtra("codigo", 0);

        //Toast.makeText(this, ""+codigo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_tricks_xml);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, lower, imageView);

        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

             Toast.makeText(TricksActivity.this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**activity_tricks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dlapps.tricksmasterizadas.tricksmasterizadas.TricksActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_tricks_xml"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_listview_tricks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="1  ATW - Around the World"
        android:id="@+id/name_xml"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/unmastered_xml"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="315dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/unmastered" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using a switch on the position?

Comment: My bad, fixed the post now with how my code is, but I can't get position even with Toast.makeText. Actually I needed each item from list open a new activity.

Comment: Do the checkboxes react?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with the setOnClickListener inside the CustomAdapter. Only when click in the items it doesn't work.

Comment: The toast looks okay, but I don't understand why you're passing a single imageview into the adapter

Comment: I'm beginner with listview and adapters, sorry if the code is a little confused.

Comment: `View r= convertView;`. Remove that line. Dont introduce a new variable. Do all with `convertView` directly.

Comment: same result with convertView directly.

Comment: So no toast. Take of the other listener for a test.

Comment: On the image button put andrroid:setFocussable="false".

Comment: already tried this before, it doesn't work. thanks anyway.

Comment: I added this inside the CustomAdapter, the click finally worked, I just don't how to get the position from each item. code: https://paste2.org/BYgD12gB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

I just added this code inside the custom_list_view.xml and finally setOnClickListener worked.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Now my layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```